# Can't keep logo in proportion to navbar as I change browser window size on React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, screen-size

How do I adjust the logo on my navbar so that it still looks proportional to all the other elements on the navbar when I change the browser window size? I tried using the media query on my css so it adapts to smaller screen size but it still doesn't seem to work and have also changed everything from px to % on css...

This is what my page usually looks like :

**Page** [image: Page]

This is my page when I reduce browser window size (looks unproportional):

**Browser window minimised**
[image: Browser window minimised]

Here's my navbar.js file code:

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

import navbarcss from "./Navbar.module.css";
import logo from "../../images/logo.jpg";
import login from "../../images/login.jpg";

function Navbar() {
  return (
    <header className={navbarcss.header}>
      <Link to="/home">
        <img className={navbarcss.logovillanueva} src={logo} alt="Logo" />
      </Link>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="/home">HOME</Link>
          </li>

          <li>
            <Link to="/about-us">ABOUT US</Link>
          </li>

          <li>
            <Link to="/firm">FIRM</Link>
          </li>

          <li>
            <Link to="/publications">PUBLICATIONS</Link>
          </li>

          <li>
            <Link to="/book-online">BOOK ONLINE</Link>
          </li>

          <li>
            <Link to="/login" style={{ display: "flex", alignItems: "center" }}>
              <img className={navbarcss.loginimg} src={login} alt="Login" />
              <span className={navbarcss.login}>Log In</span>
            </Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
  );
}

export default Navbar;
```

and here is my css code in navbar.module.css:

```css
.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 6.5rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: #554a58;
  padding: 0 5%;
}

.logovillanueva {
  width: 70%;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: 20%;
  display: flex;
}

.header ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-right: 20rem;
  margin-left: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.header li {
  margin-left: 2rem;
}

.header a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14.5px;
  color: white;
}

.header a:hover,
.header a:active,
.header a:active {
  color: #aa9fad;
}

.badge {
  background-color: #cc2062;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 12px;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  margin-left: 0.5rem;
}

.loginimg {
  width: 130%;
}

.login {
  color: #41bbbc;
}

.login:hover {
  color: #48999e;
}
```

Comment: Whenever you ask a question regarding styling, making a [mcve] is helpful. So reduce your example to CSS and HTML only and make it so that everything (except your problematic part) behaves and looks as intended by you. Also include the information about what dimension your logo has.

Comment: What do you mean by proportional? Proportional to what? To the size of the navigation bar "buttons" or that the font size of the logo is proportional to the ones of the navigation elements?

Comment: @t.niese by proportional I mean that when I reduce the screen size the ratio of the logo to the nav bar buttons is the same as when it was on full screen. So that the logo doesn't look significantly smaller then the other buttons when I reduce the screen size and so the site still looks nice when the screen size is smaller.

Comment: May not be it, but try using flex-shrink: 0 on your logo css class and see if it works. +1 to the minimal reproducible example

Comment: try adding hardcoded value of to logo width with "rem" unit